# Delete Request API Axios Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, crud, vuejs3

I'm trying to build a CRUD app connecting the front and back via API. I've got the app working with vanilla JS but I wanted to build it with Vue.js using Axios to handle the APIs. The app works with vanilla JS fetch() and when I test with Postman using Axios it works too.

But I'm doing something wrong with Axios in Vue, I think it's a problem with how I'm using "data" to collect the id to delete. Or possibly a problem with "headers". The only error thrown is from my backend PHP that returns false if mysqli_query(connection and sql delete request) isn't satisfied. The console is showing general status 200 but data status 0.

Here's the vanilla JS that's working correctly:

```
   //Function to send form data
    deleteForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        //Prevent page from reloading when the form is submitted
        e.preventDefault();

        //Collect the form data
        var deleteIDVar = document.getElementById('reviewCakeId').value;
        
        //Prepare the header
        var myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Request-Method", "POST");
        myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        
        //Prepare the body with data from the form
        var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
        urlencoded.append("ID", deleteIDVar);

        //Prepare the attributes of the post request
        var requestOptions = {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: myHeaders,
            body: urlencoded
        };
        //Make the post request with fetch
        fetch("https://*******/delete.php", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(result => console.log(result))
            .then(confirm => {
                document.getElementById("confirm").innerHTML = "Deleted!";
            })
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
    console.log(requestOptions);
    });
```

Here's the Axios from Postman, this is working correctly too:

```
var axios = require('axios');
var qs = require('qs');
var data = qs.stringify({
  'ID': '58' 
});
var config = {
  method: 'delete',
  url: 'https://******/delete.php',
  headers: { 
    'Access-Control-Request-Method': 'POST', 
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Here's what I've got in Vue with Axios, it's not working:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
   data(){
      return{
         configDelete: {
            method: 'delete',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            url: 'https://********/delete.php',
            data: {id: 58}
         }
      }
   },
   methods:{
      sendDeleteRequest(){
         axios(this.configDelete)
         .then(response => (this.cakes = response))
         .then(response => console.log(response));
      }
   }
};
```

I know I'm not using qs.stringify like the Postman example. I looked up what it is and read it wasn't needed, not sure if I've got that right. I also know that I'm not including `'Access-Control-Request-Method': 'POST',`  like the Postman version. I tried that and console throws the error `Refused to set unsafe header "Access-Control-Request-Method"`. When I remove it the status returns 200 but data has status 0 and my PHP error message.

I've looked through answers here, youtube tutorials, Axios github page, Vue official forum and loads of smaller articles and it seems like they all use Axios like this `axios.delete(url, {params: {id}}) ...` . I've tried that but got the same response if any. Very few of them go into detail about "data" or "headers". The method I'm using, `axios(config)...`, came from Postman and I'd prefer to stick close to that if possible.

I've already built the read part in Vue with Axios, it's working correctly so I know that the connection is right. Any help is appreciated.

***** ADDED ******

There's been a few comments about my PHP backend so I'll add that here:

```
<?php
//Open CORS security feature
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE');
    
//Access the database
include_once 'config.php';

//Check for incoming request
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "DELETE"){
    // Assign incoming posts to variables and sanitise them.
    $rawData = parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    $reviewCakeId = isset($ID) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $ID) : "";

    // Update the database
    $sql = "DELETE FROM `reviewtable` WHERE `id` = $reviewCakeId;";

    $post_data_query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if($post_data_query){
        $json = array("status" => 1, "Success" => "Review has been deleted successfully!");
    }
    else{
        $json = array("status" => 0, "Error" => "Error deleting! Please try again!");
    }
}
else{
    $json = array("status" => 0, "Info" => "Request method not accepted!");
}
@mysqli_close($conn);
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: You should know what your PHP expects to receive a POST payload (in JSON format) or a GET query parameter. Then you will know what to send in Axios. Supposing that your PHP code expects a POST with JSON encoded payload then you will call Axios like `axios.delete('/api/whatever/delete.php', {id: product_to_delete})`

Comment: Your PHP backend might expect the data to be provided in JSON format. You are providing a vanilla javascript object. Have you tried using `data: JSON.stringify({id: 58})`? I suspect this does the same as `qs.stringify` in your postman code sample.

Comment: Thank you Ivo and Aside.                                                                                         
Ivo: I'm not sure what you mean. The PHP header is "('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE')",so it expects the delete method, is that what you meant?  Aside, I tried JSON.stringify like you showed and it returned the same error as before, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I won't go into specifics but in general the problem (solved now) was in the difference between the Javascript fetch() method and Axios.

fetch() appears not to require PHP to decode the JSON, GET, POST, PUT and DELETE requests worked correctly without it. Axios however DOES require the PHP to decode the JSON.

Once the PHP was updated to decode in incoming request there seemed to be no problem with the API requests using Axios. The whole CRUD system is working correctly now as seen here:(http://cake-creator.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/)